# Make UIImagePickerController (Camera view) only show a certain # of pixels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

How do I make UIImagePickerController (Camera view) only show a certain # of pixels (400 * 400 perhaps).

Does this involve creating an cameraOverlayView or is there a way where can I set the constraints on the pixels able to be shot?

Any advice would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should go for adding an Overlay, since by doing so you will be able to constrain the camera view to desired rect.
http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=443
http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273